# Insert list of ImongoQuery into Query.And

Tags: c#, mongodb, database

Instead of doing this:

```
var query = Query.And(
            Query.Matches("",  new BsonRegularExpression(new Regex(""))),
            Query.Matches("",  new BsonRegularExpression(new Regex("")))

            );
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
foreach(var g in gs)
{
   Query.AddAndRange(g);
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question right, the solution is something like:

```
var query = Query.And(new BindingList<IMongoQuery>
            {
                query0,
                query1,
                query2,
                query3,
                query4,
            });
```

or

```
var list = new BindingList<IMongoQuery>();
foreach (var g in gs) list.Add(g);
var query = new Query.And(list);
```